# How can I parse querystring from webpage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse all the query string present in a page, so that using that query string I can navigate to specific page. code that I tried for doing this is as below

```
    import requests


    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from datetime import datetime


    import datetime
    import dateutil.parser
    import time
    import pytz


    """python espncricinfo library module https://github.com/dwillis/python-espncricinfo """
    from espncricinfo.match import Match 
    from espncricinfo.exceptions import MatchNotFoundError, NoScorecardError


    """----time-zone-calculation----"""
    time_zone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
    datetime_today = datetime.datetime.now(time_zone)
    datestring_today = datetime_today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


    """------URL of page to parse-------with a date of today-----""" 
    url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?date=datestring_today"
    """eg. url = http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?date=2018-02-12"""


    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


    """"------parsing for matchno------"""
    match_no = [x['href'].split('/',4)[4].split('.')[0] for x in 

    soup.findAll('a', href=True, text='Scorecard')]


    for p in  match_no:


    """ where p is a match no, e.g p = '1122282'"""
        m = Match(p) 
        m.latest_batting
        print(m.latest_batting)
```

when I print match_no I get output:

```
['8890/scorecard/1118760/andhra-vs-tamil-nadu-group-c-vijay-hazare-trophy-2017-18/', '8890/scorecard/1118743/assam-vs-odisha-group-a-vijay-hazare-trophy-2017-18/', '8890/scorecard/1118745/bengal-vs-delhi-group-b-vijay-hazare-trophy-2017-18/', '8890/scorecard/1118763/chhattisgarh-vs-vidarbha-group-d-vijay-hazare-trophy-2017-18/']
```

this page(http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?date=datestring_today") contains all the match_no of games happening on that day, I want to trim this to get match_no which is 7 digit number[1118743,1118743.1118745....], how can I do this? SO using that match_no I can pass it to the Match() so I get details of particular match which happening at that day.
PS if no match is going on the new day then match_no returns none.

Comment: I feel you need to give us a list of examples.  What does is the raw return for soup.findAll get you?

Comment: it's pretty long, you can download the module here https://github.com/dwillis/python-espncricinfo, ask me if you need to know anything else

Comment: I have no need to.  Show us an example on here. For completeness of your question, we need at least a subset of hrefs to understand what you are trying to parse.

Comment: check this out https://shrib.com/#VvY5F2Y1QiQpFzT8Ly-Y

Comment: Hey check this link https://shrib.com/#VvY5F2Y1QiQpFzT8Ly-Y, I posted empty matches data of today, sorry.

Comment: I'm looking for numbers 1134034,1118760,1118759.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is very hard to read. You need to let your code breathe and make it appealing for others to read it.

Second, what is causing issue is probably this line:

```
match_no = [x['href'].split('/',4)[4].split('.')[0] for x in soup.findAll('a', href=True, text='Scorecard')]
```

It is hard to read too. There are far more better and readable ways of parsing match id from URL.

Here is example of what should be working. I did take provisional date for matches:

```
import re

import pytz
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from espncricinfo.exceptions import MatchNotFoundError, NoScorecardError
from espncricinfo.match import Match

"""python espncricinfo library module https://github.com/dwillis/python-espncricinfo """
# from espncricinfo.match import Match


def get_match_id(link):
    match_id = re.search(r'([0-9]{7})', link)
    if match_id is None:
        return None
    return match_id.group()

# ----time-zone-calculation----
time_zone = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
datetime_today = datetime.datetime.now(time_zone)
datestring_today = datetime_today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# ------URL of page to parse-------with a date of today-----
url = "http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/index.html?date=datestring_today"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.findAll('span', {"class": "match-no"})

matches_ids = []

for s in spans:
    for a in s.findAll('a', href=lambda href: 'scorecard' in href):
        match_id = get_match_id(a['href'])
        if match_id is None:
            continue
        matches_ids.append(match_id)


# ------parsing for matchno------
for p in matches_ids:
    # where p is a match no, e.g p = '1122282'
    m = Match(p)
    m.latest_batting
    print(m.latest_batting)
```

Now, I didn't have every lib that you are using here, but this should give you an idea of how to do it.

Once again, my advice is that empty lines are your friends. They are reader's friends for sure. Make your code 'breathe'.

Comment: Sorry @ikac for my bad code, I never repeat that mistake again. Thanks for answering, I got output as I wanted,  liked your simple method of doing it ,  learned a lot of new things, thanks again.